# Какой предлог лучше употребить?

Tags: предлоги, выбор-слов

Подскажите, какой предлог лучше употребить:

1. Наш материал широко используется В северо-западной части России.
2. Наш материал широко используется ПО северо-западной части России.

Благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **Наш материал широко используется в северо-западной части России**. Но: Наш материал широко используется по всей России.

Предлог В указывает конкретную область, а предлог ПО указывает на совокупность всех частей какой-либо территории.

Сравнить: гулять в саду ― гулять по саду.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложила такой вариант, Ольга:

> Наш материал широко используется на территории северо-западной части России.